# Subtracting a list of (n,n) arrays in succession while maintaining a list of previous subtraction values

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist, subtraction

**Blockquote**

> For instance (making this slightly simpler to explain by not outlining
> this as the list of `3x3 arrays` I actually need to be subtracting by.
> `x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]`---- that's the starting matrix `0-1=-1;`
> `-1-2=-3;`
> `-3-3=-6;`
> `-6-4=-10;`
> `-10-5=-15` In this case I would want a matrix that basically shows `[-1,-3,-6,-10,-15]` I need a for loop that will solve this issue for me
> and I have tried for **HOURS**. I'm a newbie.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this blog post about how to get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this what you want.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr = []
seed = x[0]
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    seed = seed - x[i]
    arr.append(seed)

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[-1, -3, -6, -10, -15]
```